# boots only in recovery mode after update ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, updates, recovery-mode

Uhm, I need help, after performing software updates, and restarting my laptop as requested, I can no longer boot normally, I am currently posting this question using recovery mode.

When I try to boot normally, It reaches the log in screen after which, when the desktop is supposed to load, it doesn't. I can move my mouse but cant click on any icons what so ever.

Comment: Checked the link, enabled unity plug in but still doesnt work.

Comment: Do you see the icons but cannot click them? If so, please edit your question to clarify that (and if we've closed this, after editing please comment to request reopening). If your problem appears the same as in that question, please try *all* the solutions presented there, not just that one.